# menu bar effect between the lines

Tags: css, menubar

how can I make this effect of the inner side of the lines?This is the menu bar I am trying to make: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvuer.jpg I cant do the effect between the lines. This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ivailo/3q6ej7cc/4/

```
.button {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding: .5em 1em;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
border: 1px solid rgba(122, 112, 82, 0.2);
color: #877B5A;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 7px;
}

.button::after {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: -1;
color #fffff;
display: block;
content: '';
width: 15em;
height: 15em;
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transition: all 0s;
}

.button:hover::after {
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10em rgba(242, 189, 99, .2);
}

.button:hover {
color: #000000;
}

.button1 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding: .5em 1em;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
border: 1px solid rgba(122, 112, 82, 0.2);
color: #877B5A;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 7px;
}

.button1::after {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: -1;
display: block;
content: '';
width: 15em;
height: 15em;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transition: all 0s;
}

.button1:hover::after {
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10em rgba(242, 189, 99, .2);
}

.button1:hover {
color: #000000;
}

.theborder {
text-align: center;
width: 600px;
padding: 20px 25px;
}

.theborder:after {
content: "";
height: 1px;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(160, 160, 160, .7) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
display: block;
margin: 10px 0px;
} 

.theborder:before {
content: "";
height: 1px;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(160, 160, 160, .7) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
display: block;
margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean the effect of the inner side? are you talking about the white fade?

Comment: @PedroEstrada yes the white fade on the edge it also gives some kind of round effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: The inner glow**

You can achieve this effect by using a variant of the curved drop-shadow trick.  That trick is explained here:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

But instead of putting the shadow behind, we can:

1. make it white
2. leave it in front
3. set `overflow: hidden` on the menu to hide the parts of the "shadow" we don't want to see.

This produces the interior glow effect that you want.

```css
BODY {
  background-color: tan;
}

.menu {
  background-color: tan;
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  border-radius: 50% / 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.menu::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  border-radius: 50% / 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
</div>
```

You can see more clearly how it works if you remove the `overflow: hidden` from the `menu` rule.

**Step 2: The fading top border**

To make this we can just add a new `<div>` element at the top that is 1px height and has a CSS gradient background.

The final result:

```css
BODY {
  background-color: tan;
}

.menu {
  background-color: tan;
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  border-radius: 50% / 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.menu::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  border-radius: 50% / 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

.topborder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 25%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 75%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="topborder"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** in both of the above examples I have simplified things by just using the unprefixed CSS properties. These should work on the latest Chrome and FF at least. But if you need to support older browser versions, you should add the prefixed versions of the CSS properties as well.

For example for the gradients, you might want to add `-moz-linear-gradient` and `-webkit-linear-gradient`, plus the fallback filter gradients for older versions of IE.

See: [full version of this gradient](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+25,000000+75,000000+100&0+0,0.5+25,0.5+75,0+100)

Comment: Thank you men this is the effect I want, but one more think I see that on the menu I am trying to reproduce the upper line is fading. How can I do this?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also did it with another div I was wondering if there is a way to do it in the .menu div, but it works just fine have a nice day.